# Application CRUD error "HTTP 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a CRUD application and I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error, they can help. This is the error, when trying to run it with the server I get the following

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\bin;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;;C:\Users\admin\Downloads\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleJspServletDB' did not find a matching property.
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 1011 ms
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
jun 15, 2017 3:29:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
jun 15, 2017 3:29:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFORMACIÓN: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [115] milliseconds.
jun 15, 2017 3:29:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Users\admin\Desktop\libreria\tom\webapps\docs de la aplicación web
jun 15, 2017 3:29:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Users\admin\Desktop\libreria\tom\webapps\examples de la aplicación web
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1f15e3f2')
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Users\admin\Desktop\libreria\tom\webapps\host-manager de la aplicación web
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Users\admin\Desktop\libreria\tom\webapps\manager de la aplicación web
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMACIÓN: Despliegue del directorio C:\Users\admin\Desktop\libreria\tom\webapps\ROOT de la aplicación web
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
jun 15, 2017 3:29:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 1834 ms
```

How can I fix it since I have not found an answer

Comment: "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform". Get a version of the DLL for your platform

Comment: Why do you say it's a `NullPointerException`, then include a log file with no NPE? We can't help unless you show relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the wrong version of Tomcat on your machine.

Download and install the 64 bit version of Tomcat from: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi and try running the application.